# Quadrature rule for spline interpolation

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, spline, simpsons-rule

Consider an integrable function $f$ on $[-1,1]$. We denote $\left(x_j\right)_{-N}^{N}$ the equally spaced grid on $[-1,1]$, and wish to compute the integral $I = \int\limits_{-1}^{1} f(x) \, dx$ using only $f(x_j)$.

It is well known that if we interpolate $f$ using a piecewise linear  function, and integrate it, the resulting integration rule is the $\frac{1}{3}$-Simpson (composite) rule. Furthermore, if we interpolate $f$ using a piecewise quadratic function, the resulting integration is the $\frac{3}{8}$-Simpson (composite) rule.

**My question:** Is there a well known integration rule that results from integrating the cubic-spline interpolant? Could you refer to a textbook/paper that discusses it?

Comment: How about [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d95f/ded8270aed2652019398608cd93a248960bb.pdf) paper?

Comment: Thanks @caverac . I'm not entirely sure it answers my question. Also, I don't think this is the original work in which this was discovered - it should be a much earlier work.

Comment: @caverac but maybe you saw there something I didn't. In which case, I'd be happy if you could point it out

Comment: Nope! it was a just quick reference I vaguely remembered. If I find something useful I will let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting integration rule depends on the choice of end point conditions. If clamped conditions are used you get what is variably called the 'corrected trapezoidal rule' or the 'composite Hermite rule',
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx = h \left( \frac{1}{2}f_0 + f_2 + \dots + f_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}f_{n} \right) + \frac{1}{12} h^2 \left( f_0' - f_{n}' \right) + \mathcal{O}(h^4).
$$
This rule is usually derived directly from the Euler-Maclaurin formula and is indeed the simplest (apart from the trapezoidal rule) among the Euler-Maclaurin integration rules.

Different end point conditions result in different formulas of a similar type. There is a short paper by Holmes (2014), *Connections Between Cubic Splines and Quadrature Rules*, detailing the derivation of the above rule and some related results.